# Opencv findContours get wrong result in particular project

Tags: c++, opencv, contour

I have use the sample code of opencv [findContours](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html) to get the contours.

It is successful to get the correctly contours for [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heI32.png).

But when I use findContours in my project, it got the wrong contours data such like a contour have 0 point, millions of point in a contour vector and some points are huge number.

The tested code in my project list below:

```
Mat src=imread("data/artists-icon.png",1);
Mat src_gray = Mat::zeros(src.size(), CV_8UC3);
cvtColor(src, src_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);

imshow("src_gray", src_gray);

Canny(src_gray, src_gray, 100, 200, 3);
imshow("src_gray2", src_gray);

vector<vector<Point> > contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

waitKey(0);
findContours(src_gray, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));
cout << "contour size: " << contours.size() << endl;
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjRkF.png) is the image of error contours data.

And [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNNlj.png) is the correct contours data.

I have recreate my project but the problem still occurred.

How can I solve this problem?

Update:

It also wrong when I change path "/" to "\" and making CV_RGB2GRAY instead of CV_BGR2GRAY.

The image of gray and canny output list below.

Orginal:i.imgur.com/KXB6OAS.png

Gray:i.imgur.com/y1prHnj.png

Canny Output:i.imgur.com/UtUzRkh.png

Compare:i.imgur.com/lLZ8OBj.jpg

I use the library in my project: FLTK, openGL(freeglut、glew), LinearSystemLib 2005, opencv211 with gpu from my compiled.
The findcontours sample code opencv website is build with the same opencv library from my project.

Comment: Never had a problem with edge detection from opencv. Just throwing some ideas here : Did you try CV_RGB2GRAY instead of CV_BGR2GRAY?

Can we see the images (original/grayscale/after canny)?

Comment: double \\ instead of / for file path?

Comment: Please show non-working sample canny images if possible